# Android: Called Unimplemented OpenGL ES API at glMapBufferOES for OGL ES.1.1

Tags: c++, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-1.1

I am working on a port from iOS to Android NDK of an OpenGL ES 1.1 app.
I tested the port with my Nexus S device and it works fine, but as I tested it on newer devices (Nexus 4 and 5, for instance, but for other newer devices it happens the same) there's the error

**`Called unimplemented OpenGL ES API`**

when calling:

```
vbo_buffer = (GLchar*)glMapBufferOES(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY_OES);
```

For the other gl calls there is no problem, though.

**Details:**

I use OpenGL ES 1.1 with the glext package. If I print the opengl version it says:

```
07-23 10:32:51.804: D/ES1Renderer(32097): OpenGL ES Version: OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
```

In Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv1_CM -lz
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00010001" android:required="true" />
```

I use the GLSurfaceView approach from java to C/C++ OpenGL, and here is the initialization

```
public void initGLView() {
    glView = new EAGLView(getActivity(), null);

    glView.setEGLContextClientVersion(1);
    glView.setRenderer(new ES1Renderer(glView));
}
```

Being EAGLView subclass of GLSurfaceView and ES1Renderer is implementing GLSurfaceView.Renderer.

Is there anything else I should set to tell the device to use OGL ES 1.1? I do not understand why it is working fine on older devices, but fails on the newer ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entry point you are talking about is not available in OpenGL ES 1.1. However the extension, [GL_OES_mapbuffer](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_mapbuffer.txt) may be available. I would suggest you query `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` for the string `GL_OES_mapbuffer`. Then if it is available, use:

```
typedef void * (*MapBufferOESType)(GLenum, GLenum);
MapBufferOESType MapBufferOES = (MapBufferOESType)eglGetProcAddress("MapBufferOES");
```

Then try calling this entry point.

Comment: I think you are right, but on the Nexus 4/5, GL_OES_mapbuffer is not amongst the extensions available. It is, however, on the Nexus S (why?). Maybe I should try alternatives to glMapBufferOES that work on most android devices... but I guess that is another question.

Comment: That is strange, if you look at http://gfxbench.com/device.jsp?benchmark=gfx27&os=Android&api=gl&D=Google+Nexus+S&testgroup=info and open the OpenGL ES 2.0 tab you can see GL_OES_mapbuffer in the list. Maybe the extensions change depending on the GL version? You could always check if the entry points exist and ignore the string check.

Comment: Yes, actually it works on NexusS, but not on nexus 4/5, and in fact that extension is not available on nexus 4/5, so It is coherent. What I did, in the end, is replace the calls to glMapBuffer + memcpy with glBufferSubdata calls. As glBufferSubdata is not an extension, it should work on every device capable of GL.